# how to send mail using outlook and php?

Tags: php, outlook

I created a small C# console app to send mails using outlook which is very simple

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            //Create the new message by using the simplest approach.
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            oMsg.Recipients.Add("xxx@xxx.com");  //////////////////problem line 
            oMsg.Subject = "aaaa";
            oMsg.Body = "body";
            //Send the message.
            oMsg.Save();
            oMsg.Send();
```

This code needs to be invoked from php code .

1) It works in console just fine .

2) when i invoke from php i get a error .  I noticed that this console app when called from php  would run in system user. so i made outlook to run as system but i still get this error. i am running Apache server .

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004004): Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_Recipients()
   at SyncEmail.Program.sendMailUsingOutlook(String recipient, String body, String subject) in D:\NotEncrypted\Projects\SyncEmail\SyncEmail\Program.cs:line 121

I am pulling my hair out looking at different things . Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading my post .

After i say some guys say use php i decided to go php route and wrote this code and get the same error .

```
if (!defined(‘olMailItem’)) define(“olMailItem”,0);
$objApp = new COM(“Outlook.Application”);
$myItem = $objApp->CreateItem(olMailItem);
$myItem->To=’xxxx@xxx.com’;
$myItem->SentOnBehalfOfName = ‘yyy@xxyyx.com’;
$myItem->Subject=”This is a test”;
$myItem->Body=”This is a Body Section now…..!”;
$myItem->Send();
```

i get this error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception ‘com_exception’ with message ‘ in D:\NotEncrypted\xampp\htdocs\copper\system\modules\projects\index.php on line 11251
( ! ) com_exception: Error [0x80004004] Operation aborted in D:\NotEncrypted\xampp\htdocs\copper\system\modules\projects\index.php on line 11251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP` can get the JOB done directly

```
$oApp  = new COM("Outlook.Application") or die('error');
$oMsg  = $oApp ->CreateItem($oApp->OlItemTyp->olMailItem);
$oMsg ->Recipients->Add("xxx@xxx.com");
$oMsg ->Subject="aaaa";
$oMsg ->Body="body";
$oMsg ->Save();
$oMsg ->Send();
```

Comment: is there any links i can use to read about this. i am new to php thanks for the help.

Comment: https://www.google.com.ng/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+Outlook.Application   this would help

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception ‘com_exception’ with message ‘ in D:\NotEncrypted\xampp\htdocs\copper\system\modules\projects\index.php on line 11251 ( ! ) com_exception: Error [0x80004004] Operation aborted in D:\NotEncrypted\xampp\htdocs\copper\system\modules\projects\index.php on line 11251
----------------I have use php code in my original post . the error i get from .net code and php code are the same i think ..thank you.

Comment: I would uptate my code to catch all exception so that we can know the exact issue you are having

Comment: i Put a catch (Exception $e)
        {
           echo  $e->getMessage();
        }
around it and it just gave me a Error [0x80004004] Operation aborted. 
not much info .. Thank you so much for follow up.

Comment: Can see you created a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320470/how-to-make-php-outlook-application-work-and-send-mail would use then end to respond to avoid duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Create from your C# outlook project an server, and listen to port (ex 3455)
And use CURL in your php script to connect to your server(C# program)