# how to make php Outlook.Application work and send mail?

Tags: php, outlook

```
if (!defined(‘olMailItem’)) define(“olMailItem”,0);
$objApp = new COM(“Outlook.Application”);
$myItem = $objApp->CreateItem(olMailItem);
$myItem->To=’xxxx@xxx.com’;
$myItem->SentOnBehalfOfName = ‘yyy@xxyyx.com’;
$myItem->Subject=”This is a test”;
$myItem->Body=”This is a Body Section now…..!”;
$myItem->Send();
```

i get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception ‘com_exception’ with message ‘ in D:\NotEncrypted\xampp\htdocs\copper\system\modules\projects\index.php on line 11251 ( ! ) com_exception: Error [0x80004004] Operation aborted in D:\NotEncrypted\xampp\htdocs\copper\system\modules\projects\index.php on line 11251

Thanks for the comments and help guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your Outlook Component Service is not running

run

```
  Start -> run -> dcomcnfg.exe
```

To see if its there

You also need to check your windows Registry if `MAPI.Session`  is available

```
 Start -> Run -> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT  -> Outlook.Application -> MAPI.Session
```

If you can't find this then use this tutorials

http://www.digiways.com/articles/php/outlook/

Example

```
set_time_limit(10);

if (! defined ( "olMailItem" ))
{
    define ("olMailItem", 0 );
}

try {
    $objApp = new COM ( "Outlook.Application" ) or die ( "Cannot Load Outlook.Application" );
    $namespace = $objApp->GetNamespace("MAPI");  // or MAPI.Session
    $namespace->Logon();
    $myItem = $objApp->CreateItem ( olMailItem );
    $myItem->To = "xxxx@xxx.com";
    $myItem->SentOnBehalfOfName = "yyy@xxyyx.com";
    $myItem->Subject = "This is a test";
    $myItem->Body = "This is a Body Section now…..!";
    $myItem->Send ();

} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    var_dump ( $e->getMessage () );
    debug_print_backtrace ();
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I just found another solution from this page: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/php-com-automating-outlook-46167.html

Basically PHP doesn't have the constants like `olMailList`, so you have to refer to it by values. So to make your current script work change this line:

```
$myItem = $objApp->CreateItem(olMailItem);
```

to:

```
$myItem = $objApp->CreateItem(0);
```

That worked just fine for my situation.